Why is the return Value 20 when no return statement in given in int main function in C
I'm a beginner CSE student and I have a question about how the return statement works.
For the code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("Enter a's Value \n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter b's Value \n");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    printf("Sum of numbers is %d",a+b);
}

The output is:
Enter a's Value
23
Enter b's Value
62
Sum of numbers is 85
--------------------------------
Process exited after 2.972 seconds with return value 20
Press any key to continue . . .

However, when I add a return 0; at the end of the function, the output is:
Enter a's Value
23
Enter b's Value
62
Sum of numbers is 85
--------------------------------
Process exited after 4.276 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .

Why is the return value 20 in the first code, despite me not passing a return value??

The top answer of the dupe covers the implicit return in main.  If that doesn't answer the question, [edit] your question to include your exact compilation line.

@StephenNewell: How could that be a duplicate? It says main defaults to returning zero. OP asks about getting return value 20. Those are different, not a duplicate.

int main() is the only C function which is not required to explicitly return a value. If it does not, then the compiler should have added return 0;. Both C99 5.1.2.2.3 and C23 5.1.2.3.4 say ...reaching the } that terminates the
main function returns a value of 0. So it's a mystery why you have 20, unless you coded as void main(): If
the return type is not compatible with int, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified..

Why main does not return 0 here? would be a better dupe (I closed this Q and then SO retracted the close, so now I can't close again). It is the exact same situation as the code in this question. FYI, the return value is 20 because that is the return value of the final printf() in this case, and the implicit return 0; is not overwriting that value.

If you use a compiler compliant with C99 or a later version of the standard, then "falling off the end of main()" should be equivalent to return 0; — see C11 §5.1.2.2.3 Program termination: If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int, a return from the initial call to the main function is equivalent to calling the exit function with the value returned by the main function as its argument; reaching the } that terminates the main function returns a value of 0. C90 doesn't state this.

Apparently the used compiler does not comply to the standard of the last decades. :-D

It would be interesting to know which compiler you are using, because you appear to be using a compiler that in this repect does not comply with any modern ISO C standard.
